# Replace text in td that follows a td

Tags: jquery

I have the 2 td tags shown below on my page. I need to replace the `&#160;` value that is between the set of td tags that follows (not a sibling) the anchor named SPBookmark_History.

```
<td class="ms-formlabel">
 <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
  <a name="SPBookmark_History"></a>History
 </h3>
</td>
<td class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldText">&#160;</td>
```

After effecting the tags it should look like:

```
<td class="ms-formlabel">
 <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
  <a name="SPBookmark_History"></a>History
 </h3>
</td>
<td class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldText">This is my dynamically added text!</td>
```

The trouble lies in that the second TD that I want to effect is not uniquely identified by class or id, which is why I have to rely on the previous td which does have a uniquely named anchor tag.

Comment: Isn't `id="SPFieldText"` unique?

Comment: No it's not. In my excerpt it is but not on the actual page.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Sadly, I don't own the solution that writes this to the page. Its a 3rd party provider that has given us a solution that writes this nonsense to the page, ergo the cumbersome jquery that is required. I need to find the next TD after the one that is named SPBookmark_History.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the `td` elements in your HTML sample have valid `class` and/or `id` attributes which you can use to select the relevant element. From there you can call the `text()` method:

```
$('#SPFieldText').text('This is my dynamically added text!');
```

> There are numerous SPFieldText on the page just no tin my example. The only thing unique is the anchor tag name.

In which case your HTML is invalid. `id` attributes *must* be unique within the page. You should fix that.

As a workaround you can use the `class` attribute of the first `td` along with the sibling selector to select the second `td`:

```
$('td.ms-formbody + td.ms-formlabel').text('This is my dynamically added text!');
```

Comment: There are numerous SPFieldText on the page just no tin my example. The only thing unique is the anchor tag name.

Comment: That's an issue in itself that you should fix - `id` attributes have to be unique within the page. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to fix it as SharePoint writes the page content.

Comment: Ah, good old Sharepoint. The class selector should work for you though

Comment: Unfortunately that is not unique either. I should clarify that these fields are being added to the page by a third part vendor so it's not all SP's fault. But I'm unable to change those tags. Ergo the odd traversing required to get at it.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer again. This time it looks for the second `td` by class, but specifically as a sibling of the first `td`

Comment: That would find every formbody/formlabel on the page, of which there are three. Perhaps the saving grace is that it these are all inside a div with an id of ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_invoiceFieldPanel. A div surrounding a few TRs inside a table..just awful stuff.